# XSD restrict string length to one of two values?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I need an XSD restriction stating that the size has to be either 24 or 44. Doesn't matter which characters are in it, just the size.
Currently I have the following:

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:length value="44"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XSD pattern regex to constrain a string to have one of two lengths:

```
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value=".{24}|.{44}"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
```

Remember that XSD pattern regex are implicitly anchored at the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution from @kjhughes, you could define a union type with two member types, namely fixed-length 24 character strings, and fixed-length 44 character strings. That might be appropriate if the two kinds are semantically significant, or if they might be reused in other contexts.

For example, ISBNs exist in 10-character and 13-character forms, often called ISBN-10 and ISBN-13, and using these named types would point people towards their specification and historical origins.

Comment: would have considered it but the xsd isn't mine and I wanted to make the change as small as possible.